# Joining 2 tables together and using the where function based on a separate mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, distinct, where-clause

I am building a training platform for work. I have created the requirements for a user to be trained based on a role given to them. If that role is aligned to a document it will sit against the user. I have managed to get most of the way but am struglling on the best way to finish the where statement within mysqli.

tbldocfiles is a list of my files. I am looking at docid (could be multiple files associated to the document)
tbltrainingaccess sets the roles (driver, warehouseman, customer services) and shows which role (by id) is associated to the document in docfiles. 
tblusertraining is the list of users and what role they have associated to them. (driver, warehouseman, customer services).

I am listing the documents associated to the user so have thought the following is the best way:

1. Look at the user and how many roles he/she is allocated
2. Look at the roles returned in point 1 (where function)
3. Identify and match the documents that have the same roles as the user (Join function)
4. create the list, then look at the unique values for docid. (distinct value)

Example User Bri has the driver and warehouseman role.
There are 5 documents in the db, 3 of them are associated to the driver role (docid 1,2,3) and 2 of them are associated to the warehouseman role (docid 2,4) the 5th document is associayted to customerservice.

My query should do this:

List all documents associated to the roles, that are associated to the user Bri
1
2
3
2
4
Now select unique values (using docid) from the above list:
1,2,3,4.
So my answer will be a used as a count function at the end using mysql_fetch_rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbldocfiles.docid FROM tbldocfiles LEFT JOIN tbltrainingaccess ON (tbldocfiles.docid = tbltrainingaccess.docid) where groupid='1' or groupid='9'
```

The above code works. but i've got myself confused.

The where statement needs to be the result of a query similar to :
select * from tblusertrainingrole where userid='1' (1 will be a variable based on page selection)

the result in this would be 1, 9 which are the groupid results.

Basically any help would be appreciated! I am sure it will be simple but have burnt myself out on this for a while and most answers in here helped with joining but not the where statement (that I could find) 
Thank you in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a select statement in the where. Since it is an or statement you can use in for the results. Please replace * with the column name for the value you need. Should look like

```
where groupid in (select * from tblusertrainingrole where userid = '1')
```

Comment: Excellent thank you works perfectly, I hadn't 'in' before the brackets, doh!